# Can we use Two different Xib's for one View Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiview, xib

I have two different xib's. Let say we have created one xib for iPhone & another for iPad. I wanted to know how can we pass iPad xib's outlet referencing properties to the viewcontroller properties, already been set by the iPhone Xib.

I know one way of implementation is by using Size class. But i want to know how can we implement from the above approach.

Comment: You can create another xib and name it `[ViewControllerName]~ipad` and the correct one will get loaded based on device.  You just hook up the outlets the same way you do in any other xib.

Comment: Hey @dan i created two separate Xib's. But I don't want to give reference  outlets to the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

Set two Xib and set name like that

1.ViewController_ipad.XIB for ipad

2.ViewController.XIB for iphone

When you run your Project in iPhone while open iphone xib.
When you run your Project in iPad while open ipad xib.

and set logic like that

```html
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    {
        ViewController *tempView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempView  animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
         ViewController *tempView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempView  animated:YES];           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can use two different xib's for same viewController. Following is one example where we want different xib for iPhone and iPad.

```
NSString* nibName = @"ProgressViewController";

if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    nibName = @"ProgressViewController_iPad";

ProgressViewController * view = [[ProgressViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES]; // Optional if you have used navigation controller at root
```

Comment: Hey @Aamir created two separate Xib's. But I don't want to give reference outlets to the viewcontroller

Comment: What do you mean by `reference outlets to the view controller`?

Comment: what's my question is: here do I need to give property references from iPad/iPhone  or both xib to view controller ?

Comment: Please paste your code sample in question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use two xibs in single view controller.
Using this you can switch to other nib. (Xib)
    NSString* nib = @"ViewController";

```
if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    nib = @"ViewController_iPad";

ViewController * view = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nib bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

You can bind same functions with other nib objects but you have to bind every object with different names

> Like :- your label in ViewController apple  So you can put label name
>   in ViewController_iPad  apple_iPad.

It means you can use same function in both nibs but you have to use diff object bindings for both.